# Copy rotation keep offset for the bones doesn't work

Tags: rigging, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I'm following this tutorial in making IK controls for the bones. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVHKBSknFhA&list=PLyelx0TsmSpcgsINPt6fOh3yWjTjk2Nz9&index=7
The problem starts with 12:40 in the video when  the author adds Copy rotation constraints and sets the offset in order to keep toe parallel to the ground when moving foot control forward. For my mesh that doesn't work. Toe bone stays parallel to the ground as it's shown in the video but the mesh itself moves.
Here's the link for my project saved in the issued state.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16QYTn4FCY3f6jFgqNfj7yxzJ7Lk1xoGI/view?usp=sharing
Will be very grateful for the help.

Comment: The problem here is with your weights.  If we select a toe vertex in edit or weight paint mode, and look on sidebar/item/vertex weights, we can see it weighted 1.0 to both toe and foot.  So it won't follow toe exactly: it will follow toe halfway, and foot halfway.  If you want it to follow toe only, weight it only to toe.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by weighting duplicated vertices of toe and foot bones to only toe.